# SSRS reports based on Getdate() function

Tags: reporting-services

I developed a report using the getdaye() function in the query. The report runs fine on SQL management Studio.

I created a report using the SQL server data tool and the report is based on the query that I wrote in SQL studio. I have established a connection using the data source and am able to connect to the SQL database.  When I run the report using  the tool after a couple of days the report data is different from the data that I get when I run the query using SQL management studio. Obviously the Getdate() is not fetching the right date.

The report data maches only when I copy and paste the query in the SQL server data tool and then run the report.

Am I doing anything wrong or should I use create a parameter for the date and direct the default values = Now() on the sql server data tool. 
Is there any other work around for this.

Hem

Comment: I would suspect that getdate() is working fine in your query but it might be an issue with how you are using the date returned in your report. Are you using any expressions that contain your date in the report? Yo can prove the SQL is working by including the result of getdate() in you query results (you are probably doing this anyway) and running a trace from SSMS when you run your report (Tools SQL Server Profiler). you shoudl be able to see the exact query sent to your SQL server

Answer (score 2):

I guess that did not publish the report to a Report Server but repeat to preview the result in Visual Studio (SSDT). SSDT caches data to improve the experience in SSDT and retrieves data from the database only when needed. "Needed" means that you either change the query or choose different parameters. You could of course pass a parameter to the database server, but if you don't want that, you will have to clear the cache from time to time. Look into the folder where the report is saved and delete the *.data file with the same name as the report. You can make this task very easy by adding a menu command to the tools menu as described [here](http://jasonfaulkner.com/ClearDataCacheBIS.aspx).